Cannot close correctly aiortc RTCPeerConnection after client disconnect
offer:

    async def offer(self, request):
        try:
            params = await request.json()

            peer_connection = {
                "name": params["name"],
                "surname": params["surname"],
                "pc": None,
                "is_closed": False,
                "dc": None,
                "uid": uuid.uuid4(),
                "audio_track": None,
                "audio_track_for_local_use": None,
                "audio_blackhole": None,
                "video_track": None,
                "video_track_for_local_use": None,
                "video_blackhole": None,
                "offer_in_progress": True,
                "call_answered": False,
                "manage_call_end_thread": None,
                "stop_in_progress": False,
                "call_number": None
            }

            if len(list(self.pcs.keys())) == 3:
                return web.Response(content_type="application/json", text=json.dumps({"sdp": "", "type": ""}))

            reserved_call_numbers = list(self.pcs.keys())

            if 1 not in reserved_call_numbers:
                call_number = 1
            elif 2 not in reserved_call_numbers:
                call_number = 2
            else:
                call_number = 3

            peer_connection["call_number"] = call_number
            self.pcs[call_number] = peer_connection

            self.to_emitter.send({"type": "call_"+str(call_number)+"_offering", "name": peer_connection["name"], "surname": peer_connection["surname"],'uid':peer_connection['uid']})

            timer = 0
            while (timer < self.configuration["aiortc_time_window_for_answer_ms"]/1000 and self.queue.qsize() == 0 and self.pcs[call_number]["call_answered"] == False):
                if request.transport is None or request.transport.is_closing():
                    self.to_emitter.send({"type":"transport-error","call-number":call_number})
                    try:
                        request.transport.close()
                    except:
                        pass
                    del self.pcs[call_number]
                    return web.Response(content_type="application/json", text=json.dumps({"sdp": "", "type": ""}))
                timer += 0.1
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

            self.pcs[call_number]["call_answered"] = True
            if self.queue.qsize() == 0:
                return self.reject_offer(call_number,peer_connection)
            else:
                data = self.queue.get()
                correct_types = ["call-1","call-2","call-3"]
                if data["type"] in correct_types:
                    if (data["call"] == "reject"):
                        return self.reject_offer(call_number, peer_connection)
                    elif (data["call"] == "answer"):
                        while not self.queue.empty():
                            self.queue.get()

                        self.pcs[call_number]["pc"] = RTCPeerConnection(configuration=RTCConfiguration([RTCIceServer("stun:stun.l.google:19302"),]))

                        @self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].on("iceconnectionstatechange")
                        async def on_ice_connection_state_change():
                            pc = self.pcs[call_number]["pc"]
                            print(f"ICE connection state: {pc.iceConnectionState}")

                            if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
                                print("ICE connection failed. Attempting to restart ICE.")
                                await pc.restartIce()
                                await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Adjust as needed
                                if pc.iceConnectionState == "disconnected":
                                    print("Peer connection lost. Stopping connection.")
                                    await self.stop_peer_connection(call_number, self.pcs[call_number]["uid"])


                            if pc.iceConnectionState == "disconnected":
                                # Wait before handling disconnection
                                await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Adjust as needed
                                if pc.iceConnectionState == "disconnected":
                                    print("Peer connection lost. Stopping connection.")
                                    await self.stop_peer_connection(call_number, self.pcs[call_number]["uid"])

                        @self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].on("connectionstatechange")
                        async def on_connection_state_change():
                            pc = self.pcs[call_number]["pc"]
                            print(f"Connection state: {pc.connectionState}")
                            if pc.connectionState in ["failed", "disconnected", "closed"]:
                                print("Connection failed, disconnected, or closed. Stopping connection.")
                                await self.stop_peer_connection(call_number, self.pcs[call_number]["uid"])

                        @self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].on("datachannel")
                        async def on_datachannel(channel):
                            self.pcs[call_number]["dc"] = channel

                            # Send UID to the connecting peer
                            try:
                                channel.send(json.dumps({"type": "uid", "uid": str(peer_connection["uid"])}))
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(f"Error sending UID: {e}")

                            # Inform about other peers
                            try:
                                for uid, pc in self.pcs.items():
                                    if pc['uid'] != peer_connection['uid']:
                                        try:
                                            pc['dc'].send(json.dumps({
                                                "type": "other-uid",
                                                "uid": str(peer_connection['uid']),
                                                "name": peer_connection["name"],
                                                "surname": peer_connection["surname"]
                                            }))
                                        except Exception as e:
                                            print(f"Error sending other-uid message: {e}")
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(f"Error informing about other peers: {e}")

                            @channel.on("message")
                            async def on_message(message):
                                try:
                                    message = json.loads(message)
                                    msg_type = message.get("type")
                                    if msg_type == "disconnected":
                                        print('disconnected message from client')
                                        await self.stop_peer_connection(call_number, self.pcs[call_number]["uid"])
                                    elif msg_type in ["offer", "answer", "ice-candidate"]:
                                        target_uid = message["to_uid"]
                                        for uid, pc in self.pcs.items():
                                            if str(pc['uid']) == target_uid:
                                                try:
                                                    pc["dc"].send(json.dumps(message))
                                                except Exception as e:
                                                    print(f"Error relaying {msg_type}: {e}")
                                    else:
                                        print(f"Unhandled message type: {msg_type}")
                                except Exception as e:
                                    print(f"Error handling message: {e}")

                            @channel.on("close")
                            async def on_close():
                                await self.stop_peer_connection(call_number, self.pcs[call_number]["uid"])

                        # audio from server to client
                        if self.server_audio_stream_offer == None:
                            self.server_audio_stream_offer = Server_Audio_Stream_Offer(self.speackers_deck_queue,self.to_emitter)
                            #self.server_audio_stream_offer = AudioStreamTrack()

                        self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].addTrack(self.server_audio_stream_offer)

                        # video from server to client
                        if self.server_video_stream_offer is None:
                            self.server_video_stream_offer = self.create_local_tracks()
                        self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].addTrack(self.server_video_stream_offer)

                        # Attach video from server to QLabel
                        if self.server_video_track is None:
                            self.server_video_track = WebCamera(self.server_video_stream_offer,self.to_emitter)
                        if self.server_video_blackholde is None:
                            self.server_video_blackholde = MediaBlackhole()
                            self.server_video_blackholde.addTrack(self.server_video_track)
                            await self.server_video_blackholde.start()

                        @self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].on("track")
                        async def on_track(track):
                            if track.kind == "audio":
                                self.pcs[call_number]["audio_track"] = track
                                # audio from client (server use)
                                if call_number == 1:
                                    correct_queue = self.ip_call_1_packet_queue
                                elif call_number == 2:
                                    correct_queue = self.ip_call_2_packet_queue
                                else:
                                    correct_queue = self.ip_call_3_packet_queue
                                self.put_to_q = True
                                self.pcs[call_number]["audio_track_for_local_use"] = ClientTrack(track, self, self.to_emitter,call_number,self.put_to_q,correct_queue)
                                self.pcs[call_number]["audio_blackhole"] = MediaBlackhole()
                                self.pcs[call_number]["audio_blackhole"].addTrack(
                                    self.pcs[call_number]["audio_track_for_local_use"])
                                await self.pcs[call_number]["audio_blackhole"].start()
                            else:
                                self.pcs[call_number]["video_track"] = track
                                # video from client (server use)
                                self.pcs[call_number]["video_track_for_local_use"] = ClientWebCamera(track, self.to_emitter,
                                                                                                     call_number, self)
                                self.pcs[call_number]["video_blackhole"] = MediaBlackhole()
                                self.pcs[call_number]["video_blackhole"].addTrack(
                                    self.pcs[call_number]["video_track_for_local_use"])
                                await self.pcs[call_number]["video_blackhole"].start()

                        offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])

                        # handle offer
                        await self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].setRemoteDescription(offer)

                        # send answer
                        answer = await self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].createAnswer()
                        await self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].setLocalDescription(answer)

                        return web.Response(content_type="application/json", text=json.dumps(
                            {"sdp": self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].localDescription.sdp,
                             "type": self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].localDescription.type}))
                    else:
                        return self.reject_offer(call_number, peer_connection)
                else:
                    return self.reject_offer(call_number, peer_connection)
        except:
            error = traceback.format_exc()
            self.to_emitter.send({"type": "error", "error_message": error})


stop_peer_connection:
    async def stop_peer_connection(self, call_number, uid):
        try:
            if call_number not in self.pcs:
                # Peer connection does not exist
                return None
            if self.pcs[call_number]["stop_in_progress"]:
                # Stop process is already in progress
                return None
            self.pcs[call_number]["stop_in_progress"] = True
            # 1. Notify PyQt5 about the stop
            self.to_emitter.send({"type": "stop-peer-connection", "call_number": call_number})
            # 2. Empty the correct queue
            queue = self.call_queues[call_number - 1]
            while not queue.empty():
                queue.get()
            # 4. Close data channel
            try:
                self.pcs[call_number]["dc"].close()
            except Exception:
                pass
            # 5. Stop client audio track
            try:
                await self.pcs[call_number]["audio_blackhole"].stop()
            except Exception:
                pass
            # 6. Notify PyQt5 about call status
            self.to_emitter.send({"type": f"call-{call_number}-status", "status": "closed-by-client"})
            # 7. Stop client video track
            try:
                self.pcs[call_number]["video_track_for_local_use"].stop()
                await self.pcs[call_number]["video_blackhole"].stop()
            except Exception:
                pass
            # 9. Release server resources if there are no remaining connections
            if len(self.pcs.keys()) == 1:  # No active peer connections
                # Stop video relay and related blackholes
                try:
                    if self.server_video_blackholde:
                        await self.server_video_blackholde.stop()
                        self.server_video_blackholde = None
                    if self.server_video_track:
                        await self.server_video_track.stop()
                        self.server_video_track = None
                except Exception:
                    pass

                # Stop server audio stream
                try:
                    if self.server_audio_stream_offer:
                        self.server_audio_stream_offer.stop()
                        self.server_audio_stream_offer = None
                except Exception:
                    pass

                # Stop and release the webcam
                try:
                    if self.webcam:
                        if self.webcam.video:
                            self.webcam.video.stop()
                        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Give time for cleanup
                        self.webcam = None
                except Exception as e:
                    self.to_emitter.send({"type": "error", "error_message": str(e)})

                # Attempt final resource cleanup
                gc.collect()  # Force garbage collection to release resources
                self.to_emitter.send({"type": "log", "message": "Garbage collection triggered for cleanup."})

            # 3. Close peer connection
            try:
                await self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].close()
                print('Peer connection closed correctly!!!')
            except Exception:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
            # 8. Cleanup
            try:
                del self.pcs[call_number]
            except Exception:
                pass
        except Exception:
            error = traceback.format_exc()
            print(error)
            self.to_emitter.send({"type": "error", "error_message": error})

The problem with this code is that when client is disconnected, so it's send disconnect message from dc, then stop_peer_connection async method is runned, then this message:
print('Peer connection closed correctly!!!')
never printed because await self.pcs[call_number]["pc"].close() never returns

catching an exceptions and then just doing pass will basically mute any errors your program encounters. If an exception is thrown, print it in the console or log it in a file, so no errors are muted. Do this modification and run the program again and see if new errors appear that were previously hidden.
